# Regex данные между разделителями

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть файлы вида 
12312321_32423434_343434_11.01.2020_1509,92.pdf
32423_343434_343434_21.03.2020_1509.pdf
Количество разделителей всегда одинаковое, но в последнем блоке сумма может писаться как с копейками так и без. Как с помощью регулярного выражения доставть её. Пытался исключениями (?<=_).*(?=.pdf) но работает

Comment: А что, если ",92" сделать необязательным параметром, объединив их в группу. А потом для получения суммы писать что-то вроде 1509 + 92/100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде бы так:

```
\d*[.,]?\d*(?=\.pdf$)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

Может не очень оптимально, но как-то так

```
([^_]*_){4}(.*)\.pdf
```

Главное в этом выражении `_`. В последнем блоке могут быть и копейки, и точки и слово рубли - это вторая группа.